# How can I import dtdata library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code that I found on medium.com:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import dtdata as dt
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

plt.rcParams['interactive'] == True

# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(90210)
subset = -1

path =r'/home/suroot/Documents/train/daytrader/ema-crossover' # path to data
data = dt.loadData(path, subset)
(data, labels) = dt.centerAroundEntry(data)
```

But, I am not able to import the `dtdata` library. It gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dtdata (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dtdata
```

I am also not able to find any articles relating to that library regarding what is it used for. Please can anyone help me with that? I am open to alternative libraries.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error message you're getting?

Comment: if it's your code why did you include a library that you don't know ? If it's someone's else ask him about this library if you don't find it.

Comment: `dtdata` is not an open-source python library, it seems. It's someone else's personal library, that they presumably use for personal projects, and you should not use it and/or look for alternatives.